# (401) Unauthorized exception while downloading file from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, csom

I have generated an access token using OAuth mechanism for SharePoint Online server. I am using this token to create ClientContext using CSOM. While I am able to access all the sites, libraries, and folders seamlessly, I get error

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

while downloading the file from SharePoint Online. Below is the code that I am using for file download:

```
var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken("https://adventurer.sharepoint.com/Subsite1", accessToken);
var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("SubSite 1 Library 1");
string vquery = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + "6718053d-a785-489c-877f-5a4b88dcb2a7" + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = vquery;
var listItems = list.GetItems(query);
clientContext.Load(listItems, items => items.Take(1).Include(item => item.File));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var fileRef = listItems[0].File.ServerRelativeUrl;
var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);
```

I don't understand the root cause of this error, as I am passing client context with right access token. I want to know if OpenBinaryDirect has a limitation to work with access tokens? If not, what is wrong with above code? Is there any other alternative that can be used to download using access token?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After trying a lot of alternatives, I have come to conclusion that OpenBinaryDirect() cannot be used with OAuth tokens. I was able to download file from SharePoint Online using two other approaches. I am posting the answers here so that it might help someone:

**Approach 1 (OpenBinaryStream):**

```
var file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileRef);
clientContext.Load(file);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();                    
ClientResult<Stream> streamResult = file.OpenBinaryStream();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

While this approach works perfectly, `OpenBinaryStream` is not available in `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` <= v 14.0.0.0.

**Approach 2 (WebClient or Other Http Requests):**

```
string downloadUrl = HostURL + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + fileRef + "')/$value";
WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
client.DownloadFile(downloadUrl, filePath);
```

Note the download URL that I have used for WebClient. Normal file URL will not work to download files from SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

I am using C# and here is how I am currently retrieving documents from SharePoint Online. I am showing the user a list of their documents in a gridview, so I populate a DataTable with the documents. I am unsure of a way using an Access Token, but if you are able to use a Service Account like I am, then hopefully this helps you.

Namespaces

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

Object Attributes

```
SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
private string username = "";    
ClientContext context = new SP.ClientContext("https://<root>.sharepoint.com/<site collection (unless root)>/<site>");
```

Constructor (This is how I am authenticating)

```
public SharePoint()
{
    securePassword = convertToSecureString(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["O365PW"]);
    username = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["O365UN"];
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword);
}
```

Method to get documents

```
public DataTable GetDocuments(int changeID)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("ChangeDocuments");
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Columns.Add("Title");
    dt.Columns.Add("URL");
    dt.Columns.Add("ChangeID");
    dt.Columns.Add("Modified");
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");


    // The SharePoint web at the URL.
    Web web = context.Web;

    // We want to retrieve the web's properties.
    context.Load(web);

    // We must call ExecuteQuery before enumerate list.Fields. 
    context.ExecuteQuery();

   // Assume the web has a list named "Announcements". 
   SP.List oList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Name of your document library");

   // This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies Scope="RecursiveAll" 
   // so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in. 
   CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ChangeID'/>" +
    "<Value Type='Number'>" + changeID + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
   SP.ListItemCollection items = oList.GetItems(query);

   // Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query). 
   context.Load(items);
   context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listItem in items)
{
    // We have all the list item data. For example, Title. 

    dr = dt.NewRow();

    dr["Title"] = listItem["FileLeafRef"];

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(listItem["ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl"].ToString()))
    {
        dr["URL"] = "<root>/<site>/<document library>" + listItem["FileLeafRef"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        dr["URL"] = listItem["ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl"];
    }

    dr["ChangeID"] = listItem["ChangeID"];
    dr["Modified"] = Convert.ToDateTime(listItem["Modified"]).ToString("MMM.dd,yyyy h:mm tt");
    dr["ID"] = listItem["ID"];
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
 }

return dt;
}
```

Method to convert password to secure string

```
private SecureString convertToSecureString(string strPassword)
{
        var secureStr = new SecureString();
        if (strPassword.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var c in strPassword.ToCharArray()) secureStr.AppendChar(c);
        }
        return secureStr;
}
```

Comment: I am using OAuth mechanism to authenticate users to SharePoint Online. So, I am generating client context with access token. This code cannot be used in that regard: context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword);